# Prepared statement returns false, normal query returns true

Tags: php, pdo

I'm about to rip out my own hair, i've been looking at this 5 lines for the past 3 hours, and i can't for the sake of my sanity find out what's wrong with it.

The connection is fine:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$config['database']['host'].';dbname='.$config['database']['name'],$config['database']['username'],$config['database']['password']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then i run this statement:

```
$product = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM products JOIN suppliers ON products.supplier_id = suppliers.id WHERE products.partnumber=:partnumber');
$product -> execute( array( ':partnumber' => $_POST['partnumber'] ) );

$p = $product->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

if i do `var_dump($p)` it says `bool(false)`. But if i run the statement in my db manually, it finds the product perfectly fine.

Just after the beforementioned statement, i run this command:

```
$cu = current($db->query('SELECT currency_code FROM countries JOIN users ON users.country = countries.iso_alpha2 WHERE users.id="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'"')->fetch());
```

Which works perfectly fine, it returns the currency as i told it to.

So, my question it. Why doesn't my prepared statement work?

*EDIT:*

I've tried to run `$db->errorInfo`, it returns `NULL`

Comment: What does `$product->ErrorInfo()` return?

Comment: It returned nothing. I found the error, my AJAX script, for some reason, suddenly stopped sending POST vars. I went around it and used GET.

Answer (score 0):

> So, my question it. Why doesn't my prepared statement work?

As the request are trully different, there is no point comparing them.

If `execute` returns false, then it means you made an error in your request. For example, you misspelled a table name.

To debug your query, the [simplest way](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.errorinfo.php) is to use `var_dump($db->errorInfo());`.

You can also try to debug your script step by step thanks to XDebug.

Comment: Not to be rude, but did you even read the question? I have already tried to `var_dump($db->errorInfo)`m it returned `NULL`. Also, there's no typo. I literally copy+pasted the statement into my DB, and it returned the product just fine.

Comment: and try var_dump($_POST) to be sure the data inside post is good.

Comment: i'm sorry then :) i found the error though. For some reason, AJAX stopped sending `$_POST` over... Thanks for trying though